# Realloc, char**, segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

There's a function. It is add_lexem and adds an element (char *) in the end of specified array and. If no memory left, it allocates some extra memory (100 * sizeof(char *)). That function causes segfault, which is the problem.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void add_lexem(char **lexems, int *lexemsc, int *lexem_n, const char *lexem)
{
    if (*lexem_n >= *lexemsc) {
        lexems = realloc(lexems, sizeof(char *) * (*lexemsc + 100));
        *lexemsc += 100;
    }

    char *for_adding = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(lexem));
    strcpy(for_adding, lexem);
    lexems[*lexem_n] = for_adding;
    (*lexem_n)++;
}

int main(void)
{
    char **D = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    int lexemsc = 2;
    int lexem_n = 0;

    add_lexem(D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "MEOW");
    printf("%s\n", D[0]);

    add_lexem(D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "BARK");
    printf("%s\n", D[1]);

    // in this place lexem_n becomes equal lexemsc
    add_lexem(D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "KWARK"); 
    printf("%s\n", D[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output must be

```
MEOW
BARK
KWARK
```

but it is

```
MEOW
BARK
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: It would appear you're missing one level of indirection if your intent is an expansive array of `char` pointers. I.e. `D` must be passed by address as well, and the formal parameter should be `char *** lexems` (I don't like it either, as once you pass 2 levels of indirection things can go south quick, but it seems to fit what you are trying to do).

Comment: The clean way to avoid the _three star problem_ would be to put the `char **` and the size + used values into a struct together, thus also avoiding the need for three parameters to be passed by pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to avoid the three-star-programming: put everything you need inside a struct:

```
struct wordbag {
        size_t size;
        size_t used;
        char **bag;
        };

void add_lexem(struct wordbag *wb, const char *lexem)
{
    if (wb->used >= wb->size) {
        wb->bag = realloc(wb->bag, (wb->size+100) * sizeof *wb->bag );
        wb->size += 100;
    }

    wb->bag[wb->used++] = strdup(lexem);
}
```

Comment: +1 this is totally the way this should be done, as those parameters (the pointer array and the magnitude of said-same) are tightly coupled and should be kept as such in a logical structure.

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately, the OP was a bit too fast in checking your checkbox ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You're passing your `lexeme` parameter by value, when it should be by address:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// removed unused void ccat(char *str, char c)

void add_lexem(char ***lexems, int *lexemsc, int *lexem_n, const char *lexem)
{
    if (*lexem_n >= *lexemsc) {
        *lexems = realloc(*lexems, sizeof(char *) * (*lexemsc + 100));
        *lexemsc += 100;
    }

    char *for_adding = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(lexem)+1);
    strcpy(for_adding, lexem);
    (*lexems)[*lexem_n] = for_adding;
    (*lexem_n)++;
}

int main(void)
{
    char **D = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    int lexemsc = 2;
    int lexem_n = 0;

    add_lexem(&D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "MEOW");
    printf("%s\n", D[0]);

    add_lexem(&D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "BARK");
    printf("%s\n", D[1]);

    // in this place lexem_n becomes equal lexemsc
    add_lexem(&D, &lexemsc, &lexem_n, "KWARK");
    printf("%s\n", D[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
MEOW
BARK
KWARK
```

Note: Triple indirection (i.e. a 3-start-programming) is not something to enter into lightly, though it actually fits what you appear to be trying to do here. Read the above code carefully and make *sure* you understand how it works.

**Edit**: added terminator space for added string. (don't know why I missed it, since it was what everyone else seemed to be catching on first-review, duh).

Note: See [@wildplasser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23199227/1322972) to this question. Honestly it is the best way to do this, as it tightens the relationship between the string pointer array and the magnitude of said-same. If it is possible to retool your code to use that model, you should do so, and in-so-doing select that answer as the the "correct" solution.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are passing `D` to the function by value: the assignment

```
lexems = realloc(...);
```

has no effect on `D`. In cases when `realloc` performs reallocation, `D` becomes a dangling pointer, so dereferencing it becomes undefined behavior.

You need to pass `D` by pointer in the same way that you pass `lexemsc` and `&lexem_n`, so that the `realloc`'s effect would be visible inside the `main` function as well.

In addition, your `add_lexem` does not allocate enough memory for the string being copied: `strlen` does not count the null terminator, so these two lines

```
char *for_adding = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(lexem));
strcpy(for_adding, lexem);
```

write `'\0'` one byte past the allocated space.

Comment: +1: I can't believeI missed the latter of these, since it seemed to be what everyone else was catching.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from :

```
 char *for_adding = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(lexem));
  strcpy(for_adding, lexem);
```

try `char *for_adding = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(lexem)+1));` to leave some space for the '`\0` character.

Edit : and @WhozCraig seems to be right !

Bye,